# Access protected function from derived class

Tags: c++, crtp

I have the following typical scenario, in which I want to hide implementation details in a child class, and expose it through an interface:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Interface
{
public:
    void a()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->_a();
    }
};

class Implementation : public Interface<Implementation>
{
protected:
    void _a()
    {
        /*
        ...
        */
    }
};
```

I think I understand why this doesn't work, and I know that declaring the class `Interface` as friend of `Implementation` solves it, but when it comes to more complex hierarchies, like multiple interfaces, and various levels of inheritance(as is my real case), things get really messy.

I would like to avoid having to declare `friend class Interface<Implementation>` in each class that implements an interface.

Is there an alternative nice-and-clean solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Make `_a()` not protected? That or `friend` is the only way to go really.

Comment: Of course that's a solution, but then everyone could access _a(), which is what I don't want to do. Without CRTP this case is really easy, so I thought it could also be done with it

Comment: Do not expose objects of Implementation type in your module's interface then everyone can not access those.

Comment: Why can't consider impl as a `private shared_ptr` within interface class?

Comment: @Barry Why is it the only way to go? The ctor of the object of the class instantiating ``Derived`` can pass to ``Interface``'s ctor enough information on how to call it, no?

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/making-pimpl-easy/205918714?pgno=1 has a good explanation of how to make the pimpl idiom easier across large scale applications, without the need to make `Implementation` `public` or a `friend`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRTP with Protected Derived Member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523762/crtp-with-protected-derived-member)

Answer (score 1):

How about using virtual functions and polymorphism?

Create an object in your child class and reassign it to an interface class pointer or reference. Then create a pure virtual function in your interface class and define it in your child class.

Comment: That's a good idea, but CRTP is often used to avoid the cost of virtual functions.

Comment: @AmiTavory This is the first time I've heard about the CRTP idiom. I don't think I can be of much more help. But that's good to know that CRTPs eliminate the need for v-tables.

Comment: (love the name, BTW) To be precise, CRTP doesn't eliminate the need for v-tables in all cases.